# asp.net: How can I remove an item from a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist, and in some cases need to remove an item (in the code-behind).  I need to remove the item based on the value of the item.

How can I do this?

Comment: you want to remove in c# or javascript.

Answer (score 59):

You can use this:

```
myDropDown.Items.Remove(myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("TextToFind"));
```

Answer (score 19):

Code:

```
ListItem removeItem= myDropDown.Items.FindByValue("TextToFind");
drpCategory.Items.Remove(removeItem);
```

Replace "TextToFind" with the item you want to remove.

Comment: what if I want to hide multiple values ?

Comment: Loop through each one and remove one at a time.

Comment: Thanks psychoduck..I did the same thing and it worked

Answer (score 9):

```
myDropDown.Items.Remove(myDropDown.Items.FindByText("TextToFind"))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the

```
myDropDown.Items.Remove(ListItem li);
```

or

```
myDropDown.Items.RemoveAt(int index);
```

to remove it using C#.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a slightly simpler way of removing the value.

```
mydropdownid.Items.Remove("Chicago"); 
<dropdown id=mydropdown .....>
```

values

- Florida
- Texas
- Utah
- Chicago

Comment: This method worked for me in one dropdown, but in another I had to use FindByText. Just in case anyone else has trouble.

Comment: Yeah the documentation says this overload should work but sometimes it just doesn't and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have answered, you need to do;

```
myDropDown.Items.Remove(ListItem li);
```

but if you want the page to refresh asynchronously, the dropdown needs to be inside an `asp:UpdatePanel`

after you do the `Remove` call, you need to call:

```
yourPanel.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

myDropDown.Items.Remove(myDropDown.Items.FindByText("Chicago"));

Comment: While your answer applies to the question (and is probably a solution), it adds nothing new. In particular, it is a 100% duplicate of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916022/4634527

Answer (score 1):

I have Done Like this, i have remove all items except the value coming as 1 and 3.

```
ListItemCollection liCol = ddlcustomertype.Items;
for (int i = 0; i < liCol.Count;i++ )
{
    ListItem li = liCol[i];
    if (li.Value != "1" || li.Value != "3")
        ddlcustomertype.Items.Remove(li);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code.**

If you can add any item and set value in *dropdown* then try it.

```
 dropdown1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("---All---", "0"));
```

You can Removed Item in *dropdown* then try it.

```
 ListItem removeItem = dropdown1.Items.FindByText("--Please Select--");
 dropdown1.Items.Remove(removeItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add an identifying Id or class to the dropbox and remove using Javascript.

The article [here](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/list-remove.php) should help.

D

Answer (score 0):

to insert into DropDownList:

```
DropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select item --", "0"));
```

and to remove item from DropDownList:

```
DropDownList.Items.Remove(new ListItem("-- Select item --", "0"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that removal will work, since it will be a different object reference than the one already in the `Items` collection?

Comment: Outside of that, this answer doesn't really add much that wasn't already covered by e.g. [@Darshan's answer from two years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56034868/3025856).