# delete selected item in lisbox asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have this javascript function that fires when button is clicked in asp.net

```
function DeleteItem() 
    { 

        var dropDownListRef = document.getElementById("<%= lstboxFieldValues.ClientID %>"); 
        var optionsList = ''; 

        if ( dropDownListRef.value.length > 0 ) 
        { 
            var itemIndex = dropDownListRef.selectedIndex;
        if ( itemIndex >= 0 ) 
            dropDownListRef.remove(itemIndex); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            alert('Please select an item'); 
            dropDownListRef.focus(); 
            dropDownListRef.select(); 
        } 


        //for (var i=0; i<dropDownListRef.options.length; i++) 
        //{ 
        //var optionText = dropDownListRef.options[i].text;
        //var optionValue = dropDownListRef.options[i].value; 

        //if ( optionsList.length > 0 )
        //    optionsList += ';'; 
        //    optionsList += optionText; 
        //    optionsList += ';'; 
        //    optionsList += optionValue; 
        //} 

    }
```

> Source:
>   http://www.vijaykodali.com/Blog/post/2007/12/14/Add-Delete-Items-in-DropDownList2c-ListBox-using-Javascript.aspx

and it's deleting all the items in the Listbox.

what edit does it want to delete only the selected item??

Answer (score 0):

use `RemoveAt` try this code

`itemindex` is store in int value

```
dropDownListRef.Items.RemoveAt(itemIndex);
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222307/asp-net-how-can-i-remove-an-item-from-a-dropdownlist)