# Remove selected item from a DropDownList always removes the item on top

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net pages and the `summary.aspx` will be called from the first asp.net page by using `Response.Redirect("summary.aspx")`.

Ticket is a custom class with 4 attributes (`String name, int age, int seat, int price`), their getter and setters and a `ToString` method.

`Session["tickets"]` stores the objects of Ticket class

My Problem is that I have a dropdownlist called `drop_remove` and a button called `btn_remove`. When I click the button, it should remove the selected item and remove the corresponding object from `List<Ticket> tickets`. However, it always remove the top item from the dropdownlist. I am new to asp.net, please help.

```
public partial class summary : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Ticket> tickets = (List<Ticket>)Session["tickets"];

        if (Session["eventName"].ToString() != null)
        {
            label_event.Text = Session["eventName"].ToString();
        }

        if (tickets != null)
        {
            displayTickets(tickets);
        }


        if (Session["tickets"] == null)
        {
            tickets = new List<Ticket>();
        }
        else
        {
            tickets = (List<Ticket>)Session["tickets"];
            drop_remove.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Ticket a in tickets)
            {
                drop_remove.Items.Add(a.name.ToString());
            }
        }    
    }

    protected void moreTicekts_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }


    private void displayTickets(List<Ticket> tickets)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = ""; 
        System.Text.StringBuilder builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (Ticket a in tickets)
        {
            builder.Append(a.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        TextBox1.Text += builder.ToString();
    }

    protected void btn_remove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Ticket> tickets = (List<Ticket>)Session["tickets"];


        for (int i = 0; i < tickets.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tickets[i].name.Equals(drop_remove.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                drop_remove.Items.Remove(drop_remove.SelectedItem);
                tickets.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }

        Session["tickets"] = null;
        Session["tickets"] = tickets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net: How can I remove an item from a dropdownlist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222307/asp-net-how-can-i-remove-an-item-from-a-dropdownlist)

Comment: @Charlie I am able to remove items from a dropdownlist but it always remove the top most item instead of a selected item

Comment: on `Page_Load` try to add your code inside `if (!IsPostBack) { // Your code }`

Comment: Have you attached a debugger to see what SelectedItem is returning? It is inadvisable to store lists in the Session; it won't scale well. You don't need to set it to null before setting it to the new list either.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on every postback you clear out `drop_remove` inside Page_Load. As the result, the selected item was removed from the list since every item is recreated again. Then, top item becomes selected item by default.

As Wael Abbas said, you need to place those code inside `if (!IsPostBack)`.

```
public partial class summary : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!IsPostBack) 
       {
            List<Ticket> tickets = (List<Ticket>)Session["tickets"];

            // the rest of the code here
       }
   }
   ...
}
```